# Using bitwise or in mako expression

Tags: python, mako

We're converting a bunch of hand-rolled code-generation stuff over to using mako templates, and some of the code we're converting from used the bitwise or (`|`) operator to compute some of it's values.

E.g., the original was something like:

```
for my_foo in foo_constants():
    output += "#define %s_THING %d\n" % (my_foo.name, my_foo.id | 0x8000)
```

Now in mako, our first attempt was:

```
% for my_foo in foo_constants():
#define ${my_foo.name}_THING ${my_foo.id | 0x10000}
% endfor
```

But this threw the error `TypeError: 'int' object is not callable`, because mako compiled that line to:

```
__M_writer(65536(unicode(my_foo.id )))
```

Since mako uses the `|` character to mean "pipe the left to the function on the right". Surrounding the expression with an extra layer of parentheses, like `${(my_foo.id | 0x10000)}`, didn't help. It produced

```
mako.exceptions.SyntaxException: (SyntaxError) invalid syntax (<unknown>, line 1) (u'0x10000),') in file '/tmp/test_template.mako' at line: 2 char: 29
```

At the moment, we're going to just add a `bit_or` function to our template's context and call that, but as the mako documentation doesn't seem to mention this issue at all I was wondering if there's an obvious solution we're missing.

---

**Update**: As of Mako version 1.0.4, the solution is an extra layer of parentheses:

```
% for my_foo in foo_constants():
#define ${my_foo.name}_THING ${(my_foo.id | 0x10000)}
% endfor
```

(That won't work in version 1.0.3, which was the current version when this question was posted)

Comment: Maybe at some point in the future the paren method will work: https://github.com/zzzeek/mako/pull/19

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty close, you can try to just evaluate the bitwise or in the for loop. This worked for me

```
<%
    class foo(object):
        def __init__(self, name, id):
            self.name = name
            self.id = id
    foo_list = [foo('name1', 123), foo('name2', 23423), foo('name3', 3450)]
%>
% for my_foo in foo_list:
    <% foo_id = my_foo.id | 0x8000 %>
#define ${my_foo.name}_THING ${foo_id}
% endfor
```

and the output was

```
#define name1_THING 32891

#define name2_THING 56191

#define name3_THING 36218
```